# Hacer click en varios elementos de una tabla html con javascript

Tags: javascript, extensión-google-chrome

estoy haciendo una pequeña extensión de Chrome para descargar varios archivos de una tabla. Logro recorrer todas las filas de la tabla y hago clic en cada elemento, pero solo se descarga el de la última fila.

```
var table = document.getElementById("frmPrincipal:tablaCompRecibidos_data"); 
var totalfilas=table.rows.length;

for (var i = 0; i<=totalfilas ; i++) 
{ 

  document.getElementById("frmPrincipal:tablaCompRecibidos:"+i+":lnkXml").click();
 


}
```

Agradezco de antemano la ayuda.

Comment: Has comprobado que no tengas bloqueadas las descargas de múltiples ficheros? Creo recordar que por defecto en chrome vienen bloqueadas, y al hacer un loop tan rápido seguramente lo detecte como descarga múltiple

Comment: Hola y gracias por tu comentario, si configuré a chrome para que permita varias descargas, pero no importa si lo pongo en un loop o separado, Incluso intenté poner cada click en una linea separada y siempre solo me descarga el último elemento de la tabla.
Si tengo 3 o 20 instrucciones como estas, siempre se descarga de la última:
 document.getElementById("frmPrincipal:tablaCompRecibidos:3:lnkXml").click();

Comment: Sugeriría usar [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout). Así se podrían programar los clics con un tiempo entre sí (1 segundo podría ser suficiente) y probar si funciona la descarga.

Answer (score 0):

Para usar este código necesitarás permitir los "Popup" porque imagino que saltarán unos cuantos, deberían de cerrarse solos ya que son enlaces de descarga

```
var table = document.getElementById("frmPrincipal:tablaCompRecibidos_data"); 
var totalfilas=table.rows.length;

for (var i = 0; i<=totalfilas ; i++){
    //El objeto .href contiene la dirección entera del enlace del elemento
    var url = document.getElementById("frmPrincipal:tablaCompRecibidos:"+i+":lnkXml").href;
    //Abrir una nueva ventana con la url obtenida
    window.open(url, '_blank');
}
```